# how to suppress null values from the beginning of a string

Tags: text-processing

I have the below file that's getting created as an output of Hive data extraction:

```
$ cat exchangerate_ossbr-20200513133152.csv  

nullrecordtype,exchangeratetimestamp,srcfromcurrencytype,fromcurrencytypecd,fromcurrencytypeid,srctocurrencytype,tocurrencytypecd,tocurrencytypeid,exchangerate,borpremiumdiscountflag,borexchangerate,
EXCHRATE,2017-01-31T00:00:00.000,U,USD,1004010,C,CAD,1004000,1.3045000,P,0.3045000,20170131000000
null
```

I want to suppress the `null` only if they appear at the beginning of the record. In the above case, the first line and last line start with `null`.  I just want the `null` to be suppressed if they appear at the beginning of the record.

Comment: Sounds good. What have you tried so far?

Comment: (1) Are you talking about the four letters `n` `u` `l` `l` (as you have shown) or something else? (2a) Example input is like one shoe. Having one shoe is better than nothing, but it’s a ***lot*** less useful than having two. Having example input is better than nothing, but it’s a ***lot*** less useful than having example input *and the corresponding expected/desired output.* (2b) What, exactly, do you mean by suppressed? I *guess* you want the first line to be changed to `recordtype,exchangeratetimestamp,src…`, but do you want the last line to be deleted or changed to a blank line?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Or do you want both the first line and the last line to be deleted? (2c) Example input is the most valuable when it represents your real input. Does your file ever have ``null`` somewhere other than the beginning of a record? If yes, please show an example and say what you want to happen. If no, why bother saying “at the beginning of the record”?  (3) Following up on roaima’s comment: please try to solve this yourself. If you get stuck, tell us what you tried. … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it to `sed`:

```
sed 's/^null//' exchangerate_ossbr-20200513133152.csv
```